# How to apply the local timezone offset to a utc datetime with Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

If I have a DateTime in UTC, for example: `2018-05-29T02:51:39.692104`, how do I apply the current user's timezone offset to get their local time using moment.js?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `moment.local()` [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc)

```js
var date = "2018-05-29T02:51:39.692104";

var stillUtc = moment.utc(date).toDate(); //change utc time

var local = moment(stillUtc).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');//change local timezone

console.log(local);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```